# How to copy data and schema from oracle to ms sql

Tags: sql-server, oracle, schema, migration

Is there any easy way to copy `data and schema` from oracle to ms-sql.
i am using `sql server 2017` and `oracle sql developer Version 4.1.4.21`
I need one time migration.
I am using `SSMA` but getting connectivity error

[image]

Comment: Hi there, welcome to the site. Do you mean a one time migration or some sort of synchronization process? Are there any restrictions? Have you explored options but ran into problems? Please add as much detail as possible to your question so it can be answered without asking for too much clarification. Do so by [editing](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/222006/edit) your questions instead of adding clarifications in comments.

Comment: If SSMA is the right tool (I don't know if this is the case) you should ask how to resolve the connection error.

Comment: I would suspect that the MS tool would be better suited for your purpose (as much I hate to say it).  That said, a couple of observations.  First, SQL Dev 4 is very old.  The current version is 18.  Second, the error you show has nothing to do with getting to MSSQL, you aren't even reaching your Oracle DB.  Your connection definition (in SQL Dev) is incorrect.  I can't say HOW it is incorrect or what needs to be adjusted, because we don't see that information. You'd need to show a screen shot of your connection properties to get started debugging.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL Server Migration Assistant tool for Oracle. 
Details can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/oracle/migrating-oracle-databases-to-sql-server-oracletosql?view=sql-server-2017)